# Collect selected value text from a dropdown box that doesn't change anything on the element upon click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I open [this page](https://int.soccerway.com/teams/brazil/ituano-futebol-clube/340/statistics/) with selenium webdrive Firefox.

Here there is a dropdown box:

[image: PHOTOGRAPH]

```
<table class="table compare section-dropdowns">
  <thead>
    <tr class="sub-head dropdown-head">
      <th class="col1">&nbsp;</th>
      <th><div data-active-dropdown-id="" class="active-dropdown">
  <select name="competition_id">
    
      
      <option value="89" selected="selected">Serie B - 2023</option>
      
      <option value="239">Paulista A1 - 2023</option>
      
      <option value="231">Copa do Brasil - 2023</option>
    
  </select>
</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

That when selecting another option, the visual text changes, but nothing in the element changes, including it keeps saying that the first option is selected:

[image: PHOTO 2]

```
<table class="table compare section-dropdowns">
  <thead>
    <tr class="sub-head dropdown-head">
      <th class="col1">&nbsp;</th>
      <th><div data-active-dropdown-id="" class="active-dropdown">
  <select name="competition_id">
    
      
      <option value="89" selected="selected">Serie B - 2023</option>
      
      <option value="239">Paulista A1 - 2023</option>
      
      <option value="231">Copa do Brasil - 2023</option>
    
  </select>
</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

How can I get the new value of the box after selecting it while the element remains unchanged?

I tested several shapes with the webdriver and with Beautifulsoup, but none delivered correctly, including getting the text without setting any other details:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
season_opt = soup.select('table.section-dropdowns select[name="competition_id"]')[0]
season = season_opt.text.strip()
```

Comment: you want to find the <option> with "selected" attribute.  If XPATH of //option[@selected] doesn't work, then you can execute javascript to get the selected value.

Comment: Hi @pcalkins In fact, I'm not looking for ```selected```, because when you choose another option, ```selected``` keeps the old one, it doesn't update, this is the problem.

Comment: javascript should work to get value and/or text.  The <select> will have the value... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp

Comment: Hi @pcalkins I understand the case, however, if you do the test on the site, you will see that when selecting another option and the table of the new option is created, even if visually there is another value, the selected element remains unchanged as it was when opening the page. this is the point of doubt itself, how to collect the visual value if the element is unchanged.

Comment: Maybe use the Select class.  See here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/  I don't think the DOM ever updates on selection (unless there's an onchange which triggers a "look")... it's a browser-control.  The value is calculated when something retrieves it (JS) or the form is sent.  So you don't really know until you look... like schroedingers cat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `is_selected()` returns true if an element is selected, false otherwise. Following code loops through all the values, select the corresponding option and prints the selected option.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@name='competition_id']")
options = dropdown.find_elements(By.XPATH, './option')
for value in ['89','239','231']:
    Select(dropdown).select_by_value(value)
    print( [o.text for o in options if o.is_selected()] )
```

output

```
['Serie B - 2023']
['Paulista A1 - 2023']
['Copa do Brasil - 2023']
```